# How to find the best fitted models using the forward ,backward and the stepwise selection in poisson regression using R programming?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, poisson

I am using `regsubsets` method for linear regression and came across `step()` method for selecting columns for logistic regression methods.

I am not sure whether we can use `regsubsets` or `steps` for Poisson regression. It will be helpful if there is a method to find the best subsets for Poisson regression in R programming.

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be migrated to [stats.se] or closed for lack of focus/details. ThiruBalajiG, if you want a theoretical discussion then it is _far_ more appropriate to ask that on CV, though the question will still benefit from more context (and potentially sample data).

Comment: Thank you @r2evans ! do you know any links in r-programming ?

Comment: I'm not familiar/proficient in `regsubsets`; assuming the [`leaps`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaps/) package, have you gone through its reference manual (help pages)?

Comment: Yes ... it seems like it will work for linear regression but  me too not sure

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html) it looks like

- `step()` (base R: works on `glm` objects -> includes Poisson regression models)
- `bestglm` package
- `glmulti` package

Possibly others.

Be prepared for the GLM (Poisson etc.) case to be much slower than the analogous problem for Gaussian responses (OLS/`lm`).